# .Net Core SPA Angular - How to Edit Build Output Script References in Index.html

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on an Angular app and I need to edit the reference to the scripts that the build task creates and appends to the Index.html file. Where in the config files can you edit this so that the build process will prepend something to the reference path?

Ex:

runtime-es2015.c5fa8325f89fc516600b.js -> my-app/runtime-es2015.c5fa8325f89fc516600b.js

**Index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <base href="/" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.3492b62e6af093983150.css"></head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>

  <!-- How do I edit the reference to these script references in this file via the build process? -->
  <script src="runtime-es2015.c5fa8325f89fc516600b.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="runtime-es5.c5fa8325f89fc516600b.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es5.8e50a9832860f7cf804a.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es2015.5b10b8fd823b6392f1fd.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="main-es2015.6a7f9f25b686d3b5f583.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="main-es5.6a7f9f25b686d3b5f583.js" nomodule defer></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? You can use `--deploy-url` option when doing `ng build` to append a path to the scripts

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.